# Using conditionals and variables in an .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

Is it possible, using .htaccess, to include a conditional statement that is based on a variabled I've defined, perhaps in a site's specific settings in httpd.conf?

What I'd like to do is set a variable on my development server to `true`. Then, I'd like to have a conditional statement that says: `if development = true, redirect to https`

Is this possible? Is it the right way to go about things?

Comment: Why do you want to define this variable in `httpd.conf`? Better to define in .htaccess where it can be changed easily for testing different environments.

Comment: .htaccess is the same across all of my environments because it handles my routing, caching, and other things. So it isn't git-ignored and any changes would apply to every environment.

Answer (score 1):

Setup variable in Apache `httpd.conf` using:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ development=true
```

Then have this rule in your `.htaccess` which performs `if development = true, redirect to https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:development} =true
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```